# How can I write a javascript function in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have been creating a web application and I combined both sign-up and login page in the same HTML file by using a two different DIVs.When the Page Loads the "Login Div " is the only visible, and when you click on Register the "Register Div is Shown" using some JavaScript. So it works fine, but I would like to write these functions in ES6. How can I do it?

```
function Registration()
{
        const element = document.querySelector(".Registration-form"); // to give a class to the button
        const element2=document.querySelector(".login-form");
        var unhide=element.style.display="block";
        var hider=element2.style.display="none";
}
function login()
{
        const element = document.querySelector(".login-form"); // to give a class to the button
        const element2 = document.querySelector(".Registration-form"); // to give a class to the button
        var unhide=element.style.display="block";
        var hider=element2.style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "I would like to write these functions in ES6"?

Comment: You don’t really write code in ES6. At the end of the day it’s just JavaScript. ES6 adds additional features and such to the language. What specifically are you looking to do?

Comment: These functions are already fully ES6 compatible, so no idea what you are expecting. You could change the `function(){ ... }` definition into an arrow if needed `const registration = () => { ... }`, but that serves no purpose for the code shown. Sidenote: no need to assign the style changes to a variable.

Answer (score -1):

With a bit of googling I am pretty sure you could see, but here it is:

```
const registration =() => {

        const element = document.querySelector(".Registration-form");
        const element2=document.querySelector(".login-form");

        const unhide=element.style.display="block";
        const  hider=element2.style.display="none";
}
const  login = () => {
        const element = document.querySelector(".login-form"); // to give a class to the button
        const element2 = document.querySelector(".Registration-form"); // to give a class to the button
        const unhide=element.style.display="block";
        const hider=element2.style.display="none";
}
```

Those types of function are called **arrow/fat arrow** functions. You should read about them because there are instances where they do not work as intendet.

Comment: I think you mean "as expected", the arrow functions work exactly as intended :)

Comment: @James yes yes! God, I will never learn, apologies, English is my second language! :>

Comment: There's literally no reason to use arrow functions here.

Comment: This what OP wanted, how to write ES6 functions.

Comment: Those aren't ES6 functions. They're arrow functions. There's no such thing as ES6 functions.

Comment: Arrow functions are an ES6 feature for shorter function syntax with a few differences from the original functions.